# Can't get Jquery UI to work right. Need to split code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm currently having a hard time with Jquery..

I'm trying to implement https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ on my Website but sadly I can't use the code like it's on the website and this makes everything crash.

The div's with the ID's tabs-1, tabs-2, tabs-3 [...] need to go in the div named "forum_inner_container" but as soon as I split the div's with the ID's tabs-1, tabs-2, tabs-3 [...] from div with ID "tabs" nothing works anymore..

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
<?php

session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mechanics/segments_container.css"/>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class ="forum_switch_buttons_wrap">

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul style = "display:inline;">
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-1">General Discussion</a></li>
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-2">Some other</a></li>
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-3">Archive</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class = "forum_wrap">

        <div class = "forum_change_height_left">

        <div class = "forum_container_left" style = "display:block;" >

            <div class = "titlebar">

            Forum

            </div>

            <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                Topics

            </div>

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class = "forum_change_height_right">

        <div class = "forum_container_right">

            <div class = "titlebar">

            Latest Posts

            </div>

            <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                testtest

            </div>

        </div>

        </div>  

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So I basicly want something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mechanics/segments_container.css"/>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class ="forum_switch_buttons_wrap">

    <div id="tabs">
      <ul style = "display:inline;">
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-1">General Discussion</a></li>
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-2">Some other</a></li>
        <li style = "list-style-type: none;"><a class = "forum_switch_buttons" href="#tabs-3">Archive</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


</div>

<div class = "forum_wrap">

        <div class = "forum_change_height_left">

        <div class = "forum_container_left" style = "display:block;" >

            <div class = "titlebar">

            Forum

            </div>

            <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
      </div>


            </div>

        </div>

        </div>

        <div class = "forum_change_height_right">

        <div class = "forum_container_right">

            <div class = "titlebar">

            Latest Posts

            </div>

            <div class = "forum_inner_container">

                testtest

            </div>

        </div>

        </div>  

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

@Syncy Your tabs are working but css is not wokring.

**change this line**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mechanics/segments_container.css"/>
```

**To**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

(May be You forgot to include css for the tabs)

Hope its work well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as-is, except it was missing one thing... I needed to add the JQuery UI CSS file.

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It will display the latin text in a nice CSS but sadly that's not what I need. :(
I need to take the div's with ID  "tabs-1" "tabs-2" and "tabs-3"
And place it in the div names "forum_inner_container"

But then all the div texts get shown and I can't switch between them. :(

I edited my OP, maybe it's easier to understand now. :/

Comment: So you are trying to have the clickable tabs in one place and the content divs in an entirely separate location?

Comment: Yes exactly, the clickable tabs are above my Forum Container and IN the forum container itself the content should change.
Like I said above I edited my OP, maybe you understand better now what I mean :)

Comment: So you don't need jquery ui, you need to make a simple reveal boxes. You have X tabs and when you click in one tab show the related content. It's more simple and efficient than use jquery-ui (that´s a big library)

Comment: How can I achieve this? Sadly I'm not good with Javascript so I basicly need a tutorial for this part. :(

Comment: I got it done, I had to reposition many div's but now it works. :)
Thanks alot!